# Difference in following code statement

Tags: r

I'm following a machine learning course on Udemy and the instructor wrote following piece of R code to fill the missing values with mean

```
dataset = read.csv("../data.csv")

dataset$Age = ifelse(is.na(dataset$Age), 
                ave(dataset$Age, FUN = function(x) mean(x, na.rm=T)), dataset$Age)
```

I tried to re-write the code and did it without `ave` function instead I directly called the `mean` function like below.

```
dataset$Age= ifelse(is.na(dataset$Age), 
                 mean(dataset$Age, na.rm = T), dataset$Age)
```

Both the above statement returned same result.

Then I read the manual for `ave` function that it calculates **Group Averages Over Level of Combination of Factors** which all went over my head.

Wish to know is there any fundamental difference between two approaches or just a matter of preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only makes a difference if you enter an extra variable indicating the groups into the `ave` function. The code you are seeing here is basically imputing all the NA by the mean of `Age`, but you may want to use a group variable, say, `Gender`, that a female with NA should be imputed by the mean in female while a male should be imputed by male average, in that case, you would probably use sth like

```
    dataset$Age = ifelse(is.na(dataset$Age),
ave(dataset$Age, dataset$Gender,FUN = function(x) mean(x, na.rm=T)), 
dataset$Age)
```